# Why does not using a semicolon make JavaScript fail to execute a lambda function on the next line of code?

Tags: javascript, exception, syntax

Please note that I don't omit semicolons in production code.

Take the following code:

```
alert("1")
(function(){var p=[],w=window,d=document,e=f=0;p.push('ua='+encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent));e|=w.ActiveXObject?1:0;e|=w.opera?2:0;e|=w.chrome?4:0;
    e|='getBoxObjectFor' in d || 'mozInnerScreenX' in w?8:0;e|=('WebKitCSSMatrix' in w||'WebKitPoint' in w||'webkitStorageInfo' in w||'webkitURL' in w)?16:0;
    e|=(e&16&&({}.toString).toString().indexOf("\n")===-1)?32:0;p.push('e='+e);f|='sandbox' in d.createElement('iframe')?1:0;f|='WebSocket' in w?2:0;
    f|=w.Worker?4:0;f|=w.applicationCache?8:0;f|=w.history && history.pushState?16:0;f|=d.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen?32:0;f|='FileReader' in w?64:0;
    p.push('f='+f);p.push('r='+Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));p.push('w='+screen.width);p.push('h='+screen.height);var s=d.createElement('script');
    s.src='http://0.0.0.0/whichbrowser/detect.js?' + p.join('&');

    s.onreadystatechange= function () {
          if (this.readyState == 'complete') go();
       }
       s.onload= go;
    s.type="text/javascript";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    })();
```

The import parts are probably the first two lines and the last line.  Notice how there's no semicolon right after the call to `alert()`.  What happens in this case is that the alert statement will show, stating, "1," but there's an error thrown immediately afterwards, before the lambda function is entered into.  The error's text is as follows:

> alert(...) is not a function

But if you place a semicolon right after the call to `alert()` - `alert("1");` - then the error goes away, and the function executes just fine.  Why?  I thought the only time omitting a semicolon was supposed to trip up the compiler was if something else were to the right of the function call on the same line, but apparently not.

**EDIT**

One reason I'm asking this is that I do a lot with ActionScript 3.0, which is in the same family, and it does not parse things like this.  AS3 would get tripped up only if the lambda function started on the same line and to the right of the alert statement.  So I want to understand the syntactical difference here.  I'm not asking anything ambiguous or unreasonable.

Comment: This is a classical case but what kind of answer do you want ? The details of the parsing algorithm ?

Comment: is there some kind of minification involved here?

Comment: It tries to pass your anonymous function as an argument to the result of alert("1"). You need to begin line 2 with a semicolon or end line with 1 with one to prevent this.

Comment: Edited.  This is a legitimate question.

Comment: @Tsasken That may have been what the creator of the `WhichBrowser` API was up to.  He/she wrote the majority of that function.  For the alert statement, I was just using one less key press while debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert('..')
(....
```

is equivalent to

```
alert('..')(....
```

And, as the return value from `alert` is not a function, it can not be called with the rest of the code as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

> When the program contains a token that is not allowed by the formal
>   grammar, then a semicolon is inserted if (a) there is a line break at
>   that point, or (b) the unexpected token was a closing brace.

([source](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons))

In your example the token after a line break is `(`, which is allowed, so there's no implied semicolon and it reads like `alert()( function(){...} )`, and because `alert()` doesn't return a function it's a TypeError.

Compare it to this code:

```
var add2 = function(){
    return function( number ){
        return number + 2;
    }
};

var six = add2()  // a function is returned after executing add2()
                  // and no implied semicolon here by the rules cited above
(function(){ return 4; }());  // 4 is passed to the function returned from add2

console.log( six );  // logs 6!
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t64sf/

EDIT:

On the other hand you can write something like

```
var six = add2()  // unexpected token on the next line. semicolon is implied
function fn(){ return 4; } 

console.log( six ); // logs the function returned from add2()
```